# Getting error while applying loop in a nested Dictionary in python

Tags: python, nested-for-loop

I have a Nested dictionary which has some key values pair in it
and getting error while applying FOR LOOP to get the values from it. Code is like :

```
gl = { 'GLEN' : {'GLENS08907' : {'801-011-02M' : 'GLEN PART'}}
       ,'GLENS10062': {'M85049/38': 'RTIO PART'}
}

for mfr,doc in gl.items():
    print('Print Mfr is : ',mfr)
    for i, k in doc.items():
        print('Doc is : ', i)
        for key in k:
            print(key + ' : '  , k[key] )
```

I was trying to get the output like :

```
Print Mfr is :  GLEN
Doc is :  GLENS08907
801-011-02M :  GLEN PART
Doc is :  GLENS10062
M85049/38 :  RTIO PART
```

But getting error after the excution of code.

```
Print Mfr is :  GLEN
Doc is :  GLENS08907
801-011-02M :  GLEN PART
Print Mfr is :  GLENS10062
Doc is :  M85049/38
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 90, in <module>
    print(key + ' : '  , k[key] )
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Please suggest the right way to use For loop in nested dictionary.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step. Your first value is a dict of dict while the second is just a dict...

Comment: Your data structure is inconsistent. The first top-level item is three deep, but the second is only two deep. Are you sure this represents the real data structure correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dictionary `gl['GLEN'] = 'GLEN' : {'GLENS08907' : {'801-011-02M' : 'GLEN PART'}`
is have nested dictionary within nested dictionary but `gl['GLENS10062'] = {'M85049/38': 'RTIO PART'}` doesn't have nested dictionary .
So in code `print(key + ' : '  , k[key] )`  key is **R** instead of **RTIO PART**.